# replacing multiple lines in shell script with only one output file

Tags: shell, sed

I have one file `Length.txt` having multiples names (40) line by line. 
I want to write a small shell script where it will count the character count of each line of the file and if the count is less than 9 replace those lines with adding extra 8 spaces and 1 at the end of each line.

For example, if the name is

```
XXXXXX
```

replace as

```
XXXXXX        1
```

I tried with the below coding. It is working for me, however whenever it's replacing the line it is displaying all the lines at a time.
So suppose I have 40 lines in `Length.txt` and out of that 4 lines having less than 9 character count then my output has 160 lines.
Can anyone help me to display only 40 line output with the 4 changed lines?

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
#set -x

while read line;
do
count=`echo $line|wc -m`
        if [ $count -lt 9 ]
        then
        Number=`sed -n "/$line/=" Length.txt`;
        sed -e ""$Number"s/$line/$line       1/" Length4.txt
        fi
done < Length.txt
```

Comment: "Can anyone help me to display only 40 line output with the 4 changed lines?" Yes, we can help.

Answer (score 2):

A single sed command can do that:

```
sed -E 's/^.{,8}$/&        1/' file
```

To modify the contents of the file add `-i`:

```
sed -iE 's/^.{,8}$/&        1/' file
```

Partial output:

```
94605320        1
105018263
2475218231
7728563        1
        1
```

* Fixed to include only add 8 spaces not 9, and include empty lines. If you don't want to process empty lines, use `{1,8}`.

Comment: That's actually way more elegant, +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat foo.input
I am longer than 9 characters
I am also longer than 9 characters
I am not
Another long line
short

$ while read line; do printf "$line"; (( ${#line} < 9 )) && printf "        1"; echo; done < foo.input
I am longer than 9 characters
I am also longer than 9 characters
I am not        1
Another long line
short        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you what is wrong with your script. The only thing missing from your script is that you need to use `sed -i` to edit file and re-save it after making the replacement.

I'm assuming Length4.txt is just a copy of Length.txt?

I added `sed -i` to your script and it should work now:

```
cp Length.txt Length4.txt
while read line;
do
count=`echo $line|wc -m`
        if [ $count -lt 9 ]
        then
        Number=`sed -n "/$line/=" Length.txt`
        sed -ie ""$Number"s/$line/$line       1/" Length4.txt
        fi
done < Length.txt
```

However, you don't need `sed` or `wc`. You can simplify your script as follows:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    count=${#line}
    if (( count < 9 ))
    then
        echo "$line        1"
    else 
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < Length.txt > Length4.txt
```

Comment: +1 for actually pointing out the problem of the original snippet and not being as lazy as I am :-)

Comment: @user2642751 Looks like your version of `sed` doesn't support `-i`. You can use a temp file instead, like this: `sed -e ""$Number"s/$line/$line       1/" Length4.txt > Length4.tmp && mv Length4.tmp Length4.txt`. But I strongly suggest you use an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v FS= 'NF<9{$0=sprintf("%s%*s1",$0,8,"")} 1' file
XXXXXX        1
```

Note how simple it would be to check for a number other than 9 characters and to print some sequence of blanks other than 8.